# How to Save Custom Field in woo commerce session in cart page after shipping calculator

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to Save Custom Field values in WooCommerce session in cart page after shipping calculator
[cart page custom field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twm0o.png)
If I use a custom PHP session then It updates the price only when the page refreshes two times.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Sure, I share my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set and get the WooCommerce session values with the below code.

WC()->session->set( 'group_order_data', $data_values );

$data_values = WC()->session->get( 'group_order_data' );

Thanks